# Handling accented characters in xml2json

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I got encoded accented characters in my XML SOAP response such `&#xC3;&#xA9;` for `é` or `&#xC3;&#xAB;` for `ë`.

When using `toJSON()` or `toString()` functions of the [jquery-xml2json library](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/), those accented characters are transformed to `Ã©` and `Ã«` instead of `é` and `ë`.

How can I get the correct UTF-8 character instead of those specials characters?

Note: I can't change the settings on server side.

Comment: The problem is not the conversion from xml to json, the problem is that the server is sending wrongly encoded data. So you'd need to first convert the wrongly encoded XML response.

Comment: As @GregorRaýman says, the problem lies with the original encoding. Those characters should be `&#233;` and `&#235;` respectively (or in hex, `&#xE9;` and `&#xEB;`).

Comment: Is there a way to correct those bad encodings other than doing a replace() for each accented characters?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If you take a look at this http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html you'll see the characters in the xml are correct but they are in UTF-8 Bytes. The answer is not wrong then I suppose